# Tesseract training image by image

Tags: tesseract

Is there any simple way to train tesseract by giving from command line image and letter that it corresponds to? I know that there are some application that make tesseract learning easier, but I need a custom one, one image - one letter. Of course there may be few images of same letter.

Comment: I guess if you do this, there will be one font for each image. (Tesseract can put a lot of font in one traineddata file. One for each box file, one for each image...)

Comment: And will that be bad? Slow? What is the disadvantage of that?

Comment: There is no documentation on it so I don't really know. I don't want to say bullshit. However, I guess that it's better to put font as little as possible. Moreover, it's not necessarily useful to give "too" much training depending on your case. 

(As to me, I made a font that I wanted to train. I did several training with almost 2000 data, it never worked good. I tried with 4 case of my font and it works perfectly now.) Hope it helps.

Comment: And is it possible to create font with same character few times? I don't think so... :( Anyway how did you create font?

Comment: It's just what I did. And it strangely works ! I did not really create a font. I just create some filter in order to rewrite character from a bad quality picture. As a result, it gives a "new" font. If you have any question, feel free to contact me !